# How to get back to scene view after opening python console?

Tags: interface

[image: a screencap]

So, I'm *very* new to blender. I am trying to do a batch scripting project for a friend, so I'm just trying to learn the scripting/console environment. I already know python pretty well.

I found out you can press SHIFT+F4 to open the console... but after that, how do I close it? I want to see the changes I've made from the console on the scene in blender, but I can't find a way to go back to the default starting view--with the cube and the lamp and stuff. Pressing SHIFT+F4 again doesn't seem to help... I'm on a Lenovo thinkpad so I actually have to press SHIFT+FN+F4, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Also, in addition to my answer below, I highly suggest you get a full-size USB keyboard if you really want to dive into Blender. You also might want to download one of the many Blender Cheat Sheets that float around the web. Some of them have the most common shortcuts listed, others come with the complete set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Blender 2.79, you close [**Areas**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/areas.html) by dragging them by their split widget towards the area you want to close.

[image: closing areas in Blender 2.79]

By pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F-Key</kbd> (<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>), you switch the Area to a different Editor. You can also do this by clicking on the area's pop-up menu button and select a different area from there.

[image: Switch Editor in Blender 2.79]